# Fixing a NTFS hard drive that will mount but not boot

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-10, hard-drive-recovery

Something went wrong during the upgrade to Windows 10. Now I have a Windows computer that won't boot, but if I boot into Ubuntu I can mount the drive in read only mode, and copy things off of it. **Is there a way of fixing a Windows boot partition that won't boot from another computer?**

Comment: Well there are `bootsect` to fix the MBR and the boot sector and `bcdboot` to reinstall the Windows Boot Manager and BCD Store. It's just `Something went wrong during the upgrade to Windows 10`...You probably do NOT want to use the `/mbr` switch of `bootsect` if you're dual-booting Ubuntu btw.

Comment: @TomYan: I'm not dual-booting, I just don't have a windows CD handy and needed some kind of OS to look at the hard drive. Is it possible to use `bootsect` or `bcdboot` without a working windows installation?

Comment: Well they are available in the windows CD, but `I just don't have a windows CD handy`...